# listbox_DblClick() event

Tags: vba, events, listbox

I am trying to create an event for a list box multi column list box, so that when the user double clicks on an item it opens up the specified record.
I have created and displayed the list OK, but can't get the event to work.
the code is:

```
 Private Sub lstServiceHistory_DblClick()
     frmJobDetails.Show
 End Sub
```

The click event works OK, it's the dblclick that doesn't. I'm stumped.
the error is "Compile error.  Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

`ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean`

between the parenthesis following `DblClick` and let us know if that fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget parenthesis when you call the show method:

```
Private Sub lstServiceHistory_DblClick()
    frmJobDetails.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for that. It's worked a treat. This will also solve a multitude of other issues I've been having with certain events. Do you know what was causing this. P.C Putting parentheses after the the form.show caused an error, so I took it back out and all OK now.

Comment: That's how it works in VB and many other langage when you call a method or a function, you always add parenthesis. It symbolize the arguments sent to it (even when there are none). Don't forget to accept the answer if it has been useful to you ;-)

Comment: @Rubik  VBA throws an error if you include the double parenthesis after a method call. It can be confusing since basically every other programming language requires the double parenthesis.

Comment: What did I had in mind when I wrote this ?? shame on me... Good point to pointing me this ;-)